# Armature with multiple root pivots

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I am currently trying to rig a skateboard as realistically as possible. I want to be able to move and rotate everything with the Root bone (the object / "skateboard" in the picture is parented to the Root bone), but at the same time, the whole rig should also be able to rotate around the two pivot points left and right.

I know of the workaround to manually move the 3d cursor to the desired point and pivoting the object around it, but I need the solution to be based on the armature.

I tried to use the Child Of constraint fot the Root bone with the Pivot Bones as the target bones, but then either the opposite pivot point won't move with the Root or I get double deformations, when I also try to parent the Pivot Bones to the Root.

[image: One Object with 3 Bones as possible pivots]